# Was this world built by mistake?

Tags: god

Buddha does not deny God. He simply refuses to be any God because all Gods are impermanent… that is they take birth, age and then die … which is painful. Or source of sorrow.

My question is :Was this world built by mistake by some God ?

Comment: God is a metaphor.

Answer (score 2):

Buddha neither accepted nor rejected the existence of god(s) because he felt the acceptance or rejection of such was merely belief, and beliefs are a source of dukkha and tanhā (discontentment and craving). This goes equally well for your question.

- Why would you want to believe that the world was built by mistake by
  some God?
- Why would you ***not*** want to believe that?

What discontentment are you addressing in either case? What craving are you satisfying? What discontentments or cravings are you creating or destroying in others by holding this belief up for scrutiny?

The world is exactly what it is. Viewing it as a mistake is as confounding as viewing it as a perfection. You can choose to confound yourself that way if you like — sometimes that's entertaining, or interesting, or useful — but don't embrace it too heartily because it will inevitably become unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody asked good householder to take birth in what ever womb, realm, and so such questions are headed by wrong view and ingratitude.

Just as an example: BSE is surely far off from Noble intention, yet it wouldn't be proper to seek ways out which deny goodness done and taken on, even if thought as trap to supply ones own existence.

It would be certain foolish to approach one parents (first Gods) telling they made (the) a mistake in receiving the wished arrive and dwell.

May he take care of not falling to deep into the sphere of wrong view.

Support those of ingratitude is certain a mistake, or lets say, sacrifice that doesn't merit much: the path to orphanage and organized orphan use: marxism.

Comment: Do not misunderstand me. In “root of all things” Buddha says “ They perceive gods as gods. But then they identify with gods … Why is that? Because they haven’t completely understood it, I say.” Perception of God is there. I said mistake because who would create instrument of suffering?

Comment: @Dheeraj  The translation you quote offers the reader no help in comprehending the sutta. Try another one, which does: https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN1.html

Comment: @DeaneCameron I picked it up from suttacentral … didn’t know the translation differs.

Answer (score 1):

The Buddha rejected the **"Creator God"** but not the "heavenly beings".
You can see the Brahmajala sutta for reference.

World is dependently originated and no creator, according to Theravada Tipitaka.

(Some people say they understand it using the **"egg and hen puzzle"** where we can't find what is the beginning.)